# Caluclated Column If statement with Dates

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column

I need to create a calculated column in SharePoint with a text output but it includes a date+day equation. I am getting syntax error which I believe is due to the column wanting the output to be a date/time given the equation I entered. 
Is there a workaround for this issue?

Example Formula:

```
=IF([SignatureDate]<=([Date]+65),"Compiance","Non-Compliance")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried same formula and it's work for me. `=IF(StartDate<=(Date+65),"Compiance","Non-Compliance")`. just me sure column name you specify on formula that exist on list.

Comment: Your column name is rly `Compiance`? Make sure that there is no spelling difference in code and column name -> Maybe your column name is `Compliance`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make output a "Single Line of text"?
Is [Date] a column in your list?

[image]

Comment: Yes to both the Single Line of Text and Date s a column in my list

Answer (score 0):

I use your calculated formula and the column works perfectly.

Whether Date and SignatureDate columns are "Date and Time" columns?

Please check if there is no spelling problem for column name and characters in your formula. And you can create same column in another list and check if the issue exists.

Answer (score 0):

With a test list, the exact same syntax worked for me. Even worked with empty dates values. Maybe you need to analyze ULS log

```
=IF(SignatureDate<=(Date+65),"Compliance","Non-Compliance")
```

[image]